# Why did "Community" edit this answer like this?

Tags: discussion, edits, community-user

User "Community" edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32628180/1841194) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32628180/revisions). It removed the line

> And one more thing: if you are in mid-air, and press right arrow, left arrow, right arrow, left arrow, it will triple flip? Is this what you wanted, or is a mini glitch?

I can't figure out what's wrong with this line that should be removed? How does "Community" work to edit posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Community User is attributed the edit as a proxy for the *anonymous user* that made the edit suggestion here. See the [original edit suggestion review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9564266).

It means that someone without an account on Stack Overflow made a suggested improvement, and reviewers then approved that suggested edit.

Why exactly an anonymous visitor thought that that line should be removed and why 3 reviewers agreed, I don't know. At a guess the line is merely a meta-comment, not part of the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking how an automatic algorithm can do such stuff !